# How can i move page after inserting data to database?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, redirect

I'm making a  bulletin board writing page.

If the user, writes board's subject and content and press write button, it goes to the server side and insert the data to the database. After that it relocates the page to the bulletin board list page. straight and forward and easy.

But the problem is the sync.

Sometime it relocates the page before the data has been inserted.

So the user has to refresh the page to update the view.

How can I show the page **"after"** the data has been inserted to the database?

This is the code

```
                <title>Insert title here</title>
                <base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="formstyle.css">
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="buttonstyle.css">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(function(){
                        $("#writebutton").click(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: "http://10.222.223.53/test1/index.php/home/writecomplete",
                                data: {
                                    'subject': $("#subject").val(),
                                    'content': $("#content").val()
                                },
                                success: function(msg){
                                   location.href="http://10.222.223.53/test1";
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- UI Object -->
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        글쓰기 생성
                    </legend>
                    <div class="form_table">
                        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" summary="표의 요약을 반드시 넣어 주세요">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        제목
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <input type="text" style="width:320px" name="subject" title="레이블 텍스트" class="i_text" id="subject">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        내용
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="item">


                                            <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="5" title="레이블 텍스트" class="i_text" id="content"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="btn_pack medium" id="board_list"><a href="http://10.222.223.53/test1/index.php/home/gotolist">목록</a></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="btn_pack medium" id="write_complete"><input type="submit" value="작성완료" id="writebutton"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: its weird but you can do 2 redirects, as I can se you redirect by `JavaScript`, so redirect it instead to `/test1` to "redirect page" (lets say `/redirect` where in `index(){redirect('/test1');}` another tip: also try  `window.location.reload(true);` instead of `location.href...`

Comment: Redirect on success of query

Comment: All you have to do is return true from your script when the DB modifications have been completed, and the success function will not fire until the server has sent a response back. There is no `default timeout` on an $.ajax() call, even though some browsers, such as FireFox, do have such a value, it is set to `null`, so you'll be able to process for as long as you'd like until you've completed your task.

Comment: On future questions, I'd strongly recommend you remove all parts of your sample code that *are not relevant / significant* to the context of your question. It makes it easier for people to read through your code and help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<form>` element is not closed properly. Check all your other tags too.

You should be handling `.submit()`, not `.click()`.

You shouldn't be allowing the default action (submit) to proceed, which it is with the code you have.

Try this:

```
     $(".form_table").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  // prevent default 'submit'
       $.ajax({
         // do your ajax stuff here.
       });     
     });
```